# Symfony2 : Display error in error pages

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to customize my error pages but I can't get to show the eventuals errors of my error page.
Let's say i made a mistake while coding my customized 404 error page : how do I debug that error ? Also, do i make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

Override the `exception_full.html.twig` template. That one will show in dev/debug mode.